# Using a svg with params in a marker icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg

I have a svg file that accept parameters to rotate himself and it works fine using this syntax in an object tag in html:

```
<object id="myicon" data="../static/images/icons/icon.svg?trans=rotate(75 16 16)" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

But if I try to use it like an icon, doesn't work, showing only the default image heading.

```
markers[0].set("icon", "../static/images/icons/icon.svg?trans=rotate(75 16 16)")
```

or

```
markers[0].setIcon("../static/images/icons/icon.svg?trans=rotate(75 16 16)")
```

or

```
markers[0].setIcon("../static/images/icons/icon.svg?trans=rotate(75+16+16)")
```

It isn't a cache problem, if I inspect the html code generated I can see the complete url pointing to the image:

```
<img src="../static/images/icons/icon.svg?trans=rotate(75 16 16)" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none; width: auto; height: auto; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
```

What am I missing?, I want rotate the icon cleanly in any degree. Thanks.

PD: If I follow the image link in a new chrome tab from the generated code I can see the image with the right heading and the url is mapped to:

```
/images/icons/icon.svg?trans=rotate(75%2016%2016)
```

but works away of a map only.

Comment: Have you tried using urlencoded notation? `../static/images/icons/icon.svg?trans=rotate(75+16+16)`?

Comment: I tried, but does not work.

Comment: I am guessing you have tried it without the transform?

Comment: Yeah, without the transform, the image is rendered with the default image heading.

Comment: What do you mean 'default image heading'? sorry just a bit new to using SVG with Google maps... EDIT: I don't think I fully thought about that.. you mean that the image is visible but it 'faces up'

Comment: The svg is in a 0° position, the first arg of rotate set the new heading in degrees

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40499/discussion-between-christian-espinoza-and-michael-coxon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For privacy reasons if you use SVG as an image i.e. you reference it via an SVG `<image>` tag, an HTML `<img>` tag or as a background image then [amongst other things](http://longsonr.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/restrictions-on-svg-used-as-an-image/), javascript will be disabled.